# Alternative to OneHotEncoder when string are misspelled in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, similarity

In my data set, I have a categorical features which represent the name of a country, but sometimes some of them are misspelled.

For example 'France' could also be  written as 'Francz' and 'Franc'.

Do you know if there is any existing algorithm in python which converts strings to numerical values with a similarity in words. So that for my example above the value will be quite similar?

Comment: I don't think there is a tool which can do this. You might need to clean your dataset by updating the country name for such rows. Whats the frequency of such errors.  If its extremely low you can just  ignore this.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid we don't have readily available tools but you can tweak NLTK - http://www.nltk.org/ and make it work according to your requirements.

For your case

```
import nltk 
print(nltk.edit_distance("France","Francz"))
```

code prints 1, so you can write a function which has all the list of countries in the world and then run the edit_distance method on the misspelled country with the existing names and take the country name with least distance score as your correct country name.

Please see some more examples here:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12575/similarity-between-two-words